# Scala simple polymorphism

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism

I need a common (generic?) Interface JsonModel for the class "Processor" to handle JsonModel derived classes. Why the code below does not work?

```
trait JsonModel
case class LoginInfo(userid: Int, email: String, password: String) extends JsonModel
class Processor(command: String, content: String) {

  def makeLoginInfo : JsonModel = content.asJson.convertTo[LoginInfo]//Spray library

  def process = {
   command match {
     case "logininfo" => makeLoginInfo
     case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknow command")//TODO: Replace to log
   }
  }
}
def addUser(content: String) = {val loginInfo : LoginInfo = new Processor("logininfo", content).process}
```

The error message is:

```
type mismatch;
found   : JsonModel
required: LoginInfo
   val loginInfo : LoginInfo = new Processor("logininfo", content).process
                                                                ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to implicitly cast from the base class `JsonModel` to the derived class `LoginInfo`. Take a match to cast the `JsonModel` to `LoginInfo`.

```
val loginInfo: Option[LoginInfo] = new Processor("logininfo", command).process match {
    case l: LoginInfo => Some(l)
    case _ => None
}
```

If you use `Option[LoginInfo]` then also gain the use of Scala's idomatic error handling. Otherwise you can still use `null`.

To access members in an error-safe way, you should use the monad functions. (These will also work in for-comprehension.)

```
option map { _.data_value } getOrElse fallback_value

// OR... for particularly long operations
(for (inner <- option) yield inner.data_value) getOrElse fallback_value
```

Alternatively, you could make `makeLoginInfo` return a `LoginInfo`; however, once you add other elements derived from `JsonModel` to the return list of `process`, you will once again encounter this issue.

**EDIT**

Another possibility is to use a `NoLoginInfo` object.

```
class NoLoginInfo(u: Int, e: String, p: String) extends LoginInfo(u, e, p) {
    // Override and Pretend Functionality
}
val loginInfo: LoginInfo = new Processor("logininfo", command).process match {
    case l: LoginInfo => l
    case _ => new NoLoginInfo("not a user", "not an email", "not a password")
}
```

Comment: If i will use Oprtion[LoginInfo] and match, how i can convert loginInfo: Option[LoginInfo] to pure LoginInfo for accessing fields and methods of LoginInfo class e.g. loginInfo.email shows me error "Cannot resolve symbol email"?

Comment: You should use `foreach` or `map` and the `getOrElse`: `loginInfo map {_.email} getOrElse "<no-email>"`. Another option is to make a class `NoLoginInfo` that extends and pretends to be `LoginInfo` and instead of `Option[LoginInfo]`, you can just use `LoginInfo` and return `l` or a new `NoLoginInfo`.

Comment: Thanks for your tips @hsun324 ! I thought about it and decided that my original idea is a bad design.